# Service stops when deploying android app (disapears from settings>>application>>RunningServices)

Tags: android, service, background

This is my situation: I have a service running and every time I deploy my app the service disappears from `settings>>application>>runningService` (therefore, the service is not running) how can I set it so that the service does not disappears?
I have tried to `startForeground` but it did not worked.

`AndroidManifest`:

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.PhoneCallInOutService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

This is how I start the service in my Activity:

```
    chkCallsRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isChecked = chkCallsRecord.isChecked();
            updateBackgroundTasks(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

The method actually starting the service:

```
private void updateBackgroundTasks(boolean start) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhoneCallInOutService.class);             

    if (start) {
        getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);

    } else {
        getApplicationContext().stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

And here is the service:

```
public class PhoneCallInOutService extends Service {
    private TelephonyManager telephonyMgr;
    private PhoneCallStateListener pcsListener;
    private OutgoingCallReceiver ocReceiver;        

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Listener
    pcsListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(getApplicationContext(),appDto);
    telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyMgr.listen(pcsListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // Receiver
    ocReceiver = new OutgoingCallReceiver(getApplication());
    IntentFilter intentF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(ocReceiver, intentF);

    return START_STICKY;
}

    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();      

    // Listener
        telephonyMgr.listen(pcsListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

        // Receiver
        getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(ocReceiver);     
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by deploy you mean you try to launch new build of your app, then this is actually normal and expected behaviour. By deploying new build you replace old code (incl. service code) therefore it have to be killed first to avoid any crashes and other oddities. So your old iteration of app is **completely** killed. Then new app is installed and most often auto-launched. Your data create by the app usually stay, but it's also normal.

**EDIT**

For security reasons you are not allowed to re-launch itself after being updated. User has to to this. As for "*he/she may assume the service is still there running, which is not true*", use notification of type "On Going" to indicate running service

Comment: Ok, yes that is exactly what is happening ... so if there is nothing to maintain the service alive after updating to a newer version from GooglePlay (at the end a launch of a new build of the app) then, how to start the service again without waiting for the user to launch the app (he/she may assume the service is still there running, which is not true) ? a pop-up message on installation to let them know the service needs to be re-started manually though the app (how to display such a pop-up message on deploy? any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more how to use the on-going notification for this scenario? I mean, how do I trigger it (so that the user knows the service status) ? how to make use of it to let the user know the service needs re-start? thank you in advance Marcin

Comment: You create `Service` that posts `Notification` with flag ONGOING. It's all in docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html - when user see the icon on status bar he knows service is working. when there's no icon he knows it is not working so if he still needs it he needs to start your app again

Comment: I implemented it, works fine, It is a good workaround. Thank you Marcin